# Changing format of 0s in php

Tags: php

Is there a way to format 0s as blanks in php?  I know how to change the format of positive and negative values but not 0s, using something like this:

```
$final = number_format($number,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$final = $number ? number_format($number,2) : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $number = 3.12;
    if (substr(number_format($number,2), -2) == 0)
        $final = $number;
    else
        $final = number_format($number,2);
    echo $final;


?>
```

Input/ Output:

```
//number = 3.00
//Output = 3

//number = 3.12
//output = 3.12
```